# Grabbing a certain regex pattern and wrapping it's value in a new tag using XSLT

Tags: xml, regex, xslt

I have a simple enough goal for this XML:

```
<root>
  <p>Text here, 12-A</p>
  <p>Text here, 6-C to 11-D</p>
  <p>Text here, 1-D, 14-B-145, 9-E-15</p>
</root>
```

The alphanumeric combinations are cross-references that I would like to be tagged within their own `<xref>` tag so it looks like this:

```
<root>
  <p>Text here, <xref>12-A</xref></p>
  <p>Text here, <xref>6-C</xref> to <xref>11-DD</xref></p>
  <p>Text here, <xref>1-D</xref>, <xref>14-B-145</xref>, <xref>9-E-15</xref></p>
</root>
```

What I have that isn't working:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="2.0">

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="//text()[matches(., '[0-9]{1,2}-?[A-Z]{0,1}-?[0-9]{0,3}')]">
            <xsl:variable name="xref" select="." />
            <xref>
                <xsl:value-of select="$xref" />
            </xref>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't know how the xml/xslt regex work or what engine it uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [xsl:analyze-string](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string) instead...

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <p>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\d+-[A-Z](-\d+)?">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xref>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xref>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>           
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<root>
   <p>Text here, <xref>12-A</xref>
   </p>
   <p>Text here, <xref>6-C</xref> to <xref>11-D</xref>
   </p>
   <p>Text here, <xref>1-D</xref>, <xref>14-B-145</xref>, <xref>9-E-15</xref>
   </p>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a rolling optional cascade is used:

```
 # [0-9]{1,2}(?:-[A-Z](?:-[0-9]{1,3})?)?

 [0-9]{1,2} 
 (?:
      - [A-Z] 
      (?: - [0-9]{1,3} )?
 )?
```

if at least a number `-` letter is required, you can refine it to that requirement.

```
 # [0-9]{1,2}(?:-[A-Z](?:-[0-9]{1,3})?)?

 [0-9]{1,2} 
 (?:
      - [A-Z] 
      (?: - [0-9]{1,3} )?
 )
```

Either way, you have to be specific as to what to validate.
If its `number-number` that can be done too. What you have in your regex will match `0--`
But, there must be some minimally rigid framework from which to separate trivial text.